# Не работает @media запрос точнее второй @media

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, media

Первая `@media` работает как положено, а последующие нет. В чем проблема ?

```
@media  (max-width: 991px) {

    /* Nav */
    .nav {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Burger */
    .burger {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Intro */
    .intro__title {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    /*Features*/
    .features__item {
        width: 50%;
    }

}


@media (max-width: 767px) {

    /* Intro */
    .intro {
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 130px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .intro__title {
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .intro__subtitle {
        margin-bottom: 30px;

        font-size: 16px;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 425px) {

     /*Features*/
    .features__item {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй @media(min:width) and (max:width)

Comment: Я решил проблему. Ошибка была <meta neNe="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
но при этом min:width работал криво но работал.